Unknown html tag swiper-container/swiper-slide
Environment :

Ionic 7
Angular 17
Swiper 11.0.5
IDE: Webstorm 2024

Problem :
I get the error “Unknown html tag” on the swiper-container and on the swiper slide in the html file. The error is returned by the IDE.
Procedure followed :

I was initially with swiper/angular (Before v9 of swiper)
I wanted to update, so I followed this tutorial to update swiper.

Technical details :

1/ npm i swiper@latest

2/ In app.components.ts
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
register(); (also tried in constructor)

3/ In the module I'm adding the swiper to
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
@NgModule({
...
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})


Complement
I did try it on a blank project (same process).
The error is persistent.
I can launch the app with "ionic serve" and build it with "ionic build --prod --release".
But i still get the error on IDE and therefore webstorm does not provide any suggestion or recongnize any event.
For example when i add slidechange event :
Event slidechange is not emitted by any applicable directives nor by <swiper-container> element 

Question:
What could I have done wrong to keep having this problem?
I've searched but haven't found a solution to my problem.

are you using standalone components??

follow the ionic docs way: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/slides

Yes i'm using standalone components Najam.
Thanks for the ionics docs but i tried that already
